# Can I use Autofac.IContainer.Resolve with class name as string

Tags: c#

I want to get an instance of a class as shown below using AutoFac.IContainer

```
public void functionName(string classNameString)
{
var someVariable = ContainerManager.IContainer.Resolve<"classNameString">();
}
```

The problem is I dont have Type here, I am taking class name as string argument. I tried to get type and use it in Resolve but it does not work, getting error "t is a variable and used as type".

```
Type t = Type.GetType(className);
var someVariable = Autofac.IContainer.Resolve < t > ();
```

I am not sure if it is even possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should register it as a [named instance](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html). If you don't have any type information, you can register it as an object:

```
builder.RegisterType<YourClass>().Named<object>(nameof(YourClass))
```

Then to resolve it you would do:

```
container.ResolveNamed<object>("classNameString");
```

If you have type information, you wouldn't need to register it as named in the first place:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(className);
var resolved = container.Resolve(type);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am trying out your proposed solution. I am facing issue, because container.ResolveNamed<object>("classNameString"); returns object of object class. How can I cast it to MyClass type so that I can invoke function of MyClass.

Comment: Did you try the second resolve method? With Type type = [...]?